# TPL inner tasks

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I have the following code:

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    rs1.Process();
}).ContinueWith((previousTask) =>
{
    rs5.Process();
    rs6.Process();
}));

tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    rs2.Process();
}));

tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    rs3.Process();
}));

try
{
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
catch (AggregateException e)
{
}
```

when rs1.Process finishes()  rs5.Process()and rs6.Process() run synchronous. How do I run them asynchronous.

If I use inner tasks they are not being awaited

Comment: These are not "inner Tasks" , they are continuations. Try `...ContinueWith( async (previousTask) => { await Task.Run( () => rs5.Process() ); await Task.Run( () => rs6.Process() ) })); ` or something alike.

Comment: That doesnt compile

Comment: I didn't test it, you probably have to alter it to get it to compile. It's just to get the idea.

Comment: @pantonis what are the compile time errors for you , it does work for me.

Comment: ok found it. Managed to create attached tasks. See link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/attached-and-detached-child-tasks

Comment: Yep, that's even better.

Comment: Problem now is that catch(AggregateException) is not fired when I throw an ArgumentException in rs2.Process();

Comment: "Problem now is ..."  - that would be a different question.

Comment: :) Found the issue. no worries thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an inner task list:

```
tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    rs1.Process();
}).ContinueWith((previousTask) =>
{
    List<Task> loInnerTasks = new List<Task>();
    loInnerTasks.Add(Task.Run(() => rs5.Process()));
    loInnerTasks.Add(Task.Run(() => rs6.Process()));
    Task.WaitAll(loInnerTasks.ToArray());
}));
```

UPDATE (with `TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent`):

```
tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    rs1.Process();
}).ContinueWith((previousTask) =>
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => rs5.Process(), TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => rs6.Process(), TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
}));
```

Exceptions should also be caught in both ways.

Comment: If you attach the two inners tasks to the parent task I think its better https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/attached-and-detached-child-tasks

Comment: When using `TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent` you don't need the inner list. But it doesn't make any sense to add that inner Tasks to the outer list.